# how to get URL from HttpExchange?

Tags: java, html, webserver

I have this custom HTTP server but I want to be able to serve different content based on the different URLs.

How do I get the full URL from HttpExchange?

Example:

www.abcdefg.com/index.html will serve content for abcdefg

www.qrstuvwxyz.com/index.html will serve content for qrstuvwxyz

similarly, rawrrawr.abcdefg.com/index.html will serve content for abcdefg under the section rawrrawr.

or en.abcdefg.com serve english, cn.abcdefg.com serve chinese, fr.abcdefg.com serve french etc etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

As defined in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), Chapter 14.23, the "Host" header should contain that information.

So you should be able to get to that information with

```
 public void handle(final HttpExchange t) throws IOException {               
        String requestedURL = "http://"+t.getRequestHeaders().getFirst("Host") + t.getRequestURI();
        System.out.println(requestedURL);           
        URL u = new URL(requestedURL);
        System.out.println("Host: " + u.getHost());
        System.out.println("Port: " + u.getPort());
        //[...]
 }
```